# Simple Minimization, but pass into method

Tags: c#, ms-solver-foundation

I'm trying to use Solver Foundation to solve a simple one variable minimization problem (C#), but I'm new to this library and am finding an easy example hard to find...

What I'm trying to do minimize using variable x:

MIN[const - method(x)], where method(x) is a method defined in the same class.  I also have the option of replacing method(x) with an instance of some other class, which has a 'result given x' type method in it.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good "simple" example I've been using to learn Solver myself. After 2-3 readings I was able to wrap my head around the described problem and almost understand what was going on in solver =)

http://clear-lines.com/blog/post/first-steps-with-the-microsoft-solver-foundation.aspx